# How to center divi module html article tags on mobile with custom css within the module

Tags: css, wordpress, divi-theme

I'm using a custom divi module I found online and unfortunately it doesn't support mobile dynamically like I hoped it would.  On the desktop it looks as it should:

[image: Desktop]

However, on mobile the items aren't stacking and the user has to scroll right to see them.
[image: Mobile 1]
[image: Mobile 2]

Using Divi on wordpress I've tried adding the following to the custom css section within the module settings.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) 
{   
    .et_pb_post{
        display: block; 
                float: none; 
                width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This is the html with a few `<a>` and `<image>` tags stripped out.

```
<div class="et_pb_ajax_pagination_container">
    <article id="post-13643" class="et_pb_post clearfix post-13643 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-barrier-free category-shower"></article>
    <article id="post-13634" class="et_pb_post clearfix post-13634 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-barrier-free category-shower"></article>
    <article id="post-13629" class="et_pb_post clearfix post-13629 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-barrier-free category-shower"></article>
</div>
```

I expected the article tags to align vertically and stack but nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Can you provide the link to that page?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I had to change flex-direction: row; to column within my media query.